# how to create the new df from the existing df with only specific column

Tags: pandas

i am having the one data frame called matches and which contains the following column:
`id,season,city,date,team 1,team 2,toss_winner,toss_decision,result,DL_applied  winner,win_by_runs,win_by_wickets,player_of_match,venue,umpire 1,umpire 2, umpire 3`.

from this i need to create the new data frame called matches_compact which should contain the following column:
`id, season, date and winner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matches_compact=matches[['id','season','date','winner']]
```

Comment: how to find out the shape of the matches_compact?

Comment: `matches_compact.shape`